# React native Flatlist inside modal does not show data sometime

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-modal

I am trying to to data using Flatlist inside a Modal. But sometimes (Not always) data is not displayed at all. Just empty screen. I am using expo client for test. Below is my code. This render() method is actually in a custom component. So, Modal is inside a custom component. I am not sure Modal has to cause any issue here.

```
// sometime flatlist does not work when inside a modal
  render(){
    return (
          <View>
            { this.props.visible && this.renderChildModal()}
            { this.props.visible &&
            <Modal
                animationType="slide"
                transparent={false}
                visible={true}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                  //Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
                }}>
                <View>
                  <View style={this.styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={this.styles.button}
                      onPress={this.props.onDone}>
                      <Text style={styles.labelButton}>Done</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <FlatList
                    data={this.state.items}
                    extraData ={this.state}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <CheckBox
                            title={item.name}
                            checked={item.checked}
                            onPress={()=>this.onSelect(item.id-1)}  
                        />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                  />
                </View>
              </Modal>

              }          
          </View>   
    )
  }
```

Comment: Is `this.state.items` defined for sure? Try adding something else to the Modal (like listHeaderComponent) to see whether it's a problem of data or a general problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a problem with Modal. I was calling component named MultiSelect in screen as below,

```
   <MultiSelect
      items={specialities}
      selectedItems={profile.specialities}
      onItemSelected={this.onSelectedSpecialitiesChange}
      visible={this.state.specialitiesModalVisible}
      onDone={this.specialityMultiSelectDone}
    >
    </MultiSelect>
```

Sometime specialities is empty as it is retrieved from server asynchronously.

So, I changed my code as below,

```
{specialities.length>0 && 
 <MultiSelect
   items={specialities}
   selectedItems={profile.specialities}
   onItemSelected={this.onSelectedSpecialitiesChange}
   visible={this.state.specialitiesModalVisible}
   onDone={this.specialityMultiSelectDone}
 >
</MultiSelect> }
```

That solves the issue.